# Yang to Web UI forms

Tags: xml, xslt, ietf-netmod-yang

I'm looking for ideas for directly generating Web input forms from [Yang](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020) models. One complex way I came across is to use [pyang](https://code.google.com/p/pyang/) to generate XSLT and then using custom transformations to convert it into HTML forms. Appreciate your input on this approach or any alternate techniques you might suggest.

Comment: Requests for tools/libraries are off-topic, but I've tried to reformulate your request to avoid the close votes, hopefully.